# Resize image in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using URI data link with my images and I need to resize them before show them in the website. I was searching about in the web but I found only with images stored in the server. Anyone knows some tutorial or something related?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few modules like:

1. http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-image-resize
2. https://github.com/Mischi/angularjs-imageupload-directive